# How to debug shader compiler error when error message line number is wrong?

Tags: opengl, glsl

My OpenGL application loads its vertex and fragment shaders from two ascii source files. Compiling the fragment shader generates these errors:

```
0:35(22): error: operands to arithmetic operators must be numeric
0:35(17): error: cannot construct `vec4' from a non-numeric data type
0:40(31): error: too many parameters to `vec4' constructor
```

So far I’m unable to find the cause of these errors, after many hours. Here is the shader source:

```
#version 330
/*
Adapted from phong shader demo at http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~jacobson/phong-demo/
*/
/// precision MEDIUMP float;  // Generates a syntax error on non-embedded OpenGL
varying vec3 normalInterp;  // Surface normal
varying vec3 vertPos;       // Vertex position
uniform int mode;   // Rendering mode
uniform float u_Ka;   // Ambient reflection coefficient
uniform float u_Kd;   // Diffuse reflection coefficient
uniform float u_Ks;   // Specular reflection coefficient
uniform float u_shininess; // Shininess

// Material color
/// uniform vec3 u_ambientColor;
uniform vec3 u_diffuseColor;
uniform vec3 u_specularColor;
uniform vec3 u_lightPos; // Light position

varying vec4 ambientColor;

void main() {
  vec3 N = normalize(normalInterp);
  vec3 L = normalize(u_lightPos - vertPos);

  // Lambert's cosine law
  float lambertian = max(dot(N, L), 0.0);
  float specular = 0.0;
  if(lambertian > 0.0) {
    vec3 R = reflect(-L, N);      // Reflected light vector
    vec3 V = normalize(-vertPos); // Vector to viewer
    // Compute the specular term
    float specAngle = max(dot(R, V), 0.0);
    specular = pow(specAngle, u_shininess);
  }  // This is line 35!
  gl_FragColor = vec4(u_Ka * ambientColor +
                      u_Kd * lambertian * u_diffuseColor +
                      u_Ks * specular * u_specularColor, 1.0);
```

But “line 35” of the shader source file is a closing ‘}’, not an actual statement. How to interpret the line numbers on compiler error messages?
Can someone help me find these errors? How do people debug GLSL code when the error message line numbers are wrong?

Comment: How do you give this shader to OpenGL? Do you load it in a way that properly preserves the line numbering? Is this shader a raw string literal in your source, or is it a file?

Comment: I load it as a file, using QtOpenGL::addShaderFromSourceFile() (https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qglshaderprogram.html#addShaderFromSourceFile) - I assume that *should* preserve line numbers...

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, you can install GLSL language integration extension, which can catch syntax errors before compile time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look around mentioned line - the next line has an error:

```c
  gl_FragColor = vec4(u_Ka * ambientColor +
                      u_Kd * lambertian * u_diffuseColor +
                      u_Ks * specular * u_specularColor, 1.0);
```

`ambientColor` defined as `vec4` is used in the math expecting `vec3` as first argument to `vec4(rgb, a)` constructor.

So that particular lines may look like this:

```c
gl_FragColor = vec4(ambientColor.rgb * u_Ka
                  + u_diffuseColor * lambertian * u_Kd
                  + u_specularColor * specular * u_Ks, 1.0);
```

GLSL logs vary from vendor to vendor, but normally line numbers look correct in logs, as long as there is no confusion in numbering of your own GLSL code.

`0:35(22)` normally refers to 0th portion of GLSL code passed to `glShaderSource()` (as it is possible passing an array of strings, not just a single one) 35th line and 22nd column in code.

Comment: I *thought* I understood my error, but am still getting "error: too many parameters to `vec4' constructor".  I tried to convert ambientColor vec4 to a vec3 like this: vec3 aColor = vec3(ambientColor.x, ambientColor.y, ambientColor.z) - and pass aColor to the gl_fragColor constructor - but still get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried 
`gl_FragColor = vec4(ambientColor.rgb * u_Ka + u_diffuseColor * lambertian * u_Kd + u_specularColor * specular * u_Ks, 1.0);`?

Comment: Thanks @gkv311 - you have the correct answer. It turns out that vec3 aColor = vec3(ambientColor.x, ambientColor.y, ambientColor.z) does the trick. BUT - my shader made another use of ambientColor (vec4) further down in an expression that expected vec3 - so the same fix applies there. The major problem that is consuming so much debugging time is that the line numbers on error messages are not correct, making it much for difficult for me to find problems.

Comment: In the first case, the line number was just -1 to error, so it pretty close to find context. The GLSL compilation logs vary from vendor to vendor, but normally line numbers look correct. The shift might be caused by missing/extra newlines while passing GLSL code to function or by extra magic done by Qt (have not deal with it in this context).

Comment: Qt "magic" - haha! I think I'd better call an exorcist!

Comment: By magic I mean adding `#define highp`, enabling some extensions or specifying version, or something like this, when shader manager manages some compatibility for OpenGL/OpenGL ES and their different versions. But I don't know if particular Qt function does anything like this.
Note, that it is possible fetching GLSL source code back from OpenGL, to see if it is exactly the same as passed in...